# Can't upload image to QuickBlox. com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException

Tags: android, quickblox

I try to upload image to QuickBlox using QBContent class. And always catch error:

> "com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException: Connection failed. Please check your internet connection."

But all other requests works fine.
This is my code:

```
    String imagePath = "";
    Uri targetUri = data.getData();
    if (data.toString().contains("content:")) {
         imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(targetUri);
    } else if (data.toString().contains("file:")) {
         imagePath = targetUri.getPath();
    } else {
         imagePath = null;
    }
    file = new File(imagePath);
    QBFile qbfile = new QBFile();
    qbfile.setName("avatar");
    qbfile.setPublic(true);
    qbfile.setContentType(ContentType.getContentType(file));
    QBContent.createFile(qbfile).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBFile>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(QBFile file1, Bundle params) {
       Log.i("kek", ">>> File" + file1.toString());
       fileObjectAccess = file1.getFileObjectAccess();
       String paramss = fileObjectAccess.getParams();
       QBContent.uploadFileTask(file, true, null, new QBProgressCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onProgressUpdate(int progress) {
}
       }).performAsync( new QBEntityCallback<QBFile>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBFile qbFile, Bundle params) {
               qbFile.getName();
               }
        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException error) {
                                error.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
                    }

         @Override
         public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {
                        errors.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Make sure the time on your device is correct..

Comment: Time is correct. I tested on my real phone and android emulator. Thank you!